# Is it possible to print UTF-8 string with Boost and STL in windows console?

Tags: c++, boost, utf-8, stl

I'm trying to output UTF-8 encoded string with cout with no success. I'd like to use Boost.Locale in my program. I've found some info regarding windows console specific. For example, this article http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/locale/doc/html/running_examples_under_windows.html says that I should set output console code page to 65001 and save all my sources in UTF-8 encoding with BOM. So, here is my simple example:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <boost/locale.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::locale;

int wmain(int argc, const wchar_t* argv[])
{
    //system("chcp 65001 > nul"); // It's the same as SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8)
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);

    locale::global(generator().generate(""));

    static const char* utf8_string = u8"♣☻▼►♀♂☼";

    cout << "cout: " << utf8_string << endl;
    printf("printf: %s\n", utf8_string);

    return 0;
}
```

I compile it with Visual Studio 2015 and it produces the following output in console:

```
cout: ���������������������
printf: ♣☻▼►♀♂☼
```

Why does printf do it well and cout don't? Can locale generator of Boost help with it? Or should I use somethong other to print UTF-8 text in console in stream mode (cout-like approach)?

Comment: I think you need to use `std::ostream::imbue` on `cout` with the right locale in order for `cout` to print the character correctly

Comment: I tried std::cout.imbue(std::locale()) but it works the same as without this call. By the way, boost::filesystem::path::imbue(std::locale()) make Boost's filesystem to use UTF-8 for narrow character buffers. So, it seams there is something bad in cout implementation. I also found big articles https://alfps.wordpress.com/2011/11/22/unicode-part-1-windows-console-io-approaches/ and https://alfps.wordpress.com/2011/12/08/unicode-part-2-utf-8-stream-mode/ where one man implemented correct behaviour for cout and other std streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `std::cout` is much too clever here: it tries to interpret your utf8 encoded string as an ascii one and finds 21 non ascii characters that it outputs as the unmapped character `�`. AFAIK Windows C++ console driver,insists on each character from a narrow char string being mapped to a position on screen and does not support multi bytes character sets.

Here what happens under the hood:

utf8_string is the following char array (just look at a Unicode table and do the utf8 conversion):

```
utf8_string = { '0xe2', '0x99', '0xa3', '0xe2', '0x98', '0xbb', '0xe2', '0x96',
    '0xbc', '0xe2', '0x96', '0xba', '0xe2', '0x99', '0x80', '0xe2', '0x99',
    '0x82', '0xe2', '0x98', '0xbc', '\0' };
```

that is 21 characters none of which is in the ascii range 0-0x7f.

On the opposite side, `printf` just outputs the byte without any conversion giving the correct output.

I'm sorry but even after many searches I could not find an easy way  to correctly display UTF8 output on a windows console using a narrow stream such as `std::cout`.

But you should notice that your code fails to imbue the booster locale into `cout`

Comment: Thank you for your replay, now I understand. I think, I can format strings using Boost.Locale and display theirs c_str() using puts. At least it will work in UNIX-like systems and in Windows console with 65001 code page.

Answer (score 1):

The key problem is that implementation of `cout << "some string"` after long and painful adventures calls `WriteFile` for every character.

If you'd like to debug it, set breakpoint inside `_write` function in `write.c` file of CRT sources, write something to `cout` and you'll see all the story.

So we can rewrite your code

```
static const char* utf8_string = u8"♣☻▼►♀♂☼";
cout << utf8_string << endl;
```

with equivalent (and faster!) one:

```
static const char* utf8_string = u8"♣☻▼►♀♂☼";
const size_t utf8_string_len = strlen(utf8_string);
DWORD written = 0;
for(size_t i = 0; i < utf8_string_len; ++i)
    WriteFile(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), utf8_string + i, 1, &written, NULL);
```

output: `���������������������`

Replace cycle with single call of `WriteFile` and UTF-8 console gets brilliant:

```
static const char* utf8_string = u8"♣☻▼►♀♂☼";
const size_t utf8_string_len = strlen(utf8_string);
DWORD written = 0;
WriteFile(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), utf8_string, utf8_string_len, &written, NULL);
```

output: `♣☻▼►♀♂☼`

I tested it on msvc.2013 and msvc.net (2003), both of them behave identically.

Obviously windows implementation of console wants a whole characters at a call of `WriteFile`/`WriteConsole` and cannot take a UTF-8 characters by single bytes. :)

What we can do here?

My first idea is to make output buffered, like in files. It's easy:

```
static char cout_buff[128];
cout.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(cout_buff, sizeof(cout_buff));
cout << utf8_string << endl; // works
cout << utf8_string << endl; // do nothing
```

output: `♣☻▼►♀♂☼` (only once, I explain it later)

First issue is console output become delayed, it waits until end of line or buffer overflow.

Second issue — it doesn't work.

Why? After first buffer flush (at first `<< endl`) `cout` switch to bad state (`badbit` set). That's because of `WriteFile` normally returns in `*lpNumberOfBytesWritten` number of written **bytes**, but for UTF-8 console it returns number of written **characters** (problem described [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/543801/unicode-issues-with-writefile-and-in-the-crt)). CRT detects, that number of bytes requested to write and written is different and stops writing to 'failed' stream.

What we can do more?

Well, I suppose that we can implement our own `std::basic_streambuf` to write console correct way, but it's not easy and I have no time for it. If anyone want, I'll be glad.

Another decisions are (a) use `std::wcout` and strings of `wchar_t` characters, (b) use `WriteFile`/`WriteConsole`. Sometimes that solutions can be accepted.

Working with UTF-8 console in Microsoft versions of C++ is really horrible.